How do I get my customReader's method to transfer chunks over to my customerWriters write(Chunk<> chunk) method in a Spring Batch step?
I am trying to to create a batch program in Spring that calls my database, through the reader using JdbcCursorItemReader. After the item reader is created, I assume the step takes care of iterating through it. next is dealing with the writer, I want to call the write(Chunk<> chunks) method that I override from ItemWriter<>, but it never calls it. and when I do (Assume I put customReader.read() in the reader() in step builder) I can't do the same with write(Chunk<> chunks) since it takes in a parameter.
I have gotten an implementation to work, where I create two functions in my Configuration file reader() and writer(), where reader calls the read() in customReader returning an item reader. Then I iterate through it, adding each entry into a Chunk(List) I created outside the methods. Then I would return the reader when it became null. Then when writer was called in the writer part of the step builder, I called the method in my config again, but this time the writer one. It would take that Chunk(List) I made outside the methods, and use it as a parameter to the write() in my customWriter class. then I would just return my customWriter object I injected. This was inspired by what I saw in the documentation.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/step/chunk-oriented-processing.html
But this, from what I have heard is not how it should be done, since that's springs job to do, and I could confuse it when the job gets bigger or something like that. Something about the .chunk(chunkSize,transactionManager) step, still not sure.
I was hoping for some guidance in this problem I have. If you would like more information, do not hesitate to ask.
Edit:
Providing Code of working case that might not be best practice
Reader:
public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> itemReader() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("We are in the database reader");


    PreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter=new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            //code...
        }
    };

    Chunk<MyEntity> items=new Chunk();

    JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatementSetter);
    itemReader.setName("name");
    itemReader.setSql("SQL"); //assume there is code in there and it works
    itemReader.setRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper());

    return itemReader;
}

Writer:
@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends MyEntity> chunk) throws Exception {
    NamedParameterJdbcOperations namedParameterJdbcTemplate=new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    System.out.println("Hello!");


    chunk.forEach(myEntity ->

        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().batchUpdate("SQL", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                // set values on sql
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return chunk.size(); // or any other value you want
            }
        })

    );
    chunk.forEach(myEntity ->
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().batchUpdate("SQL" +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?,?,true)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    // set values on sql
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return chunk.size(); // or any other value you want
                }
            })
    );
}

Batch Config:
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Config {

    private CustomReader customReader;

    private CustomWriter customWriter;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public Config(DataSource dataSource,CustomReader customReader,CustomWriter customWriter){
        this.customReader=customReader;
        this.customWriter=customWriter;
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource){
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }




    Chunk<myEntity> chunks;
    public ItemReader<myEntity> reader() throws Exception {
        chunks=new Chunk<>();
        JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader=customReader.itemReader();
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        itemReader.open(executionContext);
        Object myEntity = new Object();
        while(myEntity != null){
            myEntity = itemReader.read();
            if(myEntity==null) break;
            chunks.add(myEntity);
            System.out.println(myEntity);
        }
        return itemReader;
    }
    
    public ItemWriter<myEntity> writer() throws Exception {
        consoleItemWriter.write(chunks);
        return consoleItemWriter;
    }
    @Bean
    public Job myEntityJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step myEntityStep){
        return new JobBuilder("myEntityJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(myEntityStep)
                .build();
    }



    @Bean
    public Step myEntityStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilder("myEntityStep", jobRepository)
                .<MyEntity,MyEntity>chunk(10,transactionManager)
                .reader(reader(databaseReader))
                .writer(writer(consoleItemWriter))
                .build();
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // System.exit is common for Batch applications since the exit code can be used to
        // drive a workflow
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(
                Config.class, args)));
    }
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide the code snippet

Done @драган-јованковић

You should not try to manually read and write your chunks. SpringBatch handle things in chunks or mapper oriented way.
You can try the following implementation :
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> itemReader(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM my_table"); // Replace with your SQL query
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new CustomRowMapper());

        return itemReader;
    }
}

For the writer :
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<MyEntity> {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public CustomWriter(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyEntity> items) throws Exception {
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().batchUpdate("INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
               // here replace with the columns you want insert
                MyEntity myEntity = items.get(i);
                ps.setString(1, myEntity.getColumn1());
                ps.setString(2, myEntity.getColumn2());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return items.size();
            }
        });
    }
}

Now for the step config :
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class StepConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> itemReader;

 @Autowired
 private CustomWriter itemWriter;

    @Bean
        public Step myEntityStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("myEntityStep", jobRepository)
                .<MyEntity, MyEntity>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .writer(itemWriter)
            .build();
    }
}


I can see why you did JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader in the steps parameters, since you put a @Bean on top of the method in BatchConfiguration. But where is ItemWriter itemWriter, coming from?

@ogra itemWriter in this case is CustomWriter implemented.

So from what I understand, it's implementation can be found in the constructor of the BatchConfig? Or is it somewhere else? Because you create a reader in the Batch Config, then only show how the CustomWriter class should be done, leaving it up to spring, how does I get it to appear in my step, because I am getting the error:
"Factory method 'myEntityStep' threw exception with message: ItemWriter must be provided"

@ogra check again my solution, it was a dependency injection issue, and please let me know if my solution works.

The reader works fine, since it runs the print statements I have in there. Since there is a Bean right on top of the method I can see how it associates it with JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader. But for write, it is not printing the print statement I have in write(Chunk<? extends MyEntity> chunk). My CustomWrite class does have the Component annotation on it. But I don't know how to make it call write(Chunk<? extends TimePeriod> chunk).

@ogra could you please check again and let me know if it works ? I updated the solution.

@ogra in case it works, please mark it as a solution.

It does not work, but it may be due to a deeper problem in my code. I will try to figure things out and come back to this post later.

@ogra if you have an error or something in the logs that stands out, feel free to share it.

Thank you, it's not that it doesn't work, it's just that write() isn't being called at all. The program runs perfectly fine, just not taking the next step in calling write().

Turns out EnableBatchProcessing is no longer used, this whole time my job was not running and I asked the wrong question. Thank you for your help!
